# Use React to implement a page with fixed navbar and collapsible fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to implement a page with fixed navbar and collapsible fixed sidebar, using **React** and **chakra-ui** component. Below are the example code.

```
import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box display="flex">
      <Box position="fixed" width="200px" height="100%" bg="red" /> {/* Sidebar */}
      <Box flex="1" position="fixed">
        <Box position="fixed" top="0" width="100%" height="50px" bg="blue" /> {/* Navbar */}
        <Box mt="50px" p="4">
          {/* Rest content */}
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

But now the width of the top navbar never meets my expectations. This is its current output.

[image: current output]

I want to achieve the following output.

[image: expected]

The red box is the sidebar and the blue box is the top navbar. Both of them are expected to be fixed on their current position. Please offer some advice on how to achieve my expectation. I will appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Give the red box a top position of 0 and then make sure it’s z-index is higher than the blue box.

Comment: Please read about CSS Layout - The position Property you can find your answer for topbar. and read about conditional rendering in react and animation to do your sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Writing it this way does achieve the effect shown in the picture. But if implement it this way, the width of the blue Box will still be the whole screen, not the width of the screen minus the width of the red Box. If I want to put my main page content in the remaining part of the white, the width of this content will also be the width of the whole screen, which will make the whole page layout rather strange. Is there a way to achieve the above effect by changing the width of the modified blue Box?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
<Box position="fixed" top="0" right="0" width="calc(100vh - 200px)" height="50px" bg="blue" /> {/* Navbar */}
```

notice that 200px is the sidebar width

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this layout component. it have header and collapsible sider.**

also you can checkout more with chakra-ui at [chakra-sidebar-layout-components](https://choc-ui.com/docs/application-shells/sidebar-layouts)

```
const Layout = () => {
    const sidebar = useDisclosure();
    const integrations = useDisclosure();
    const color = useColorModeValue("gray.600", "gray.300");
  
    const NavItem = (props) => {
      const { icon, children, ...rest } = props;
      return (
        <Flex
          align="center"
          px="4"
          pl="4"
          py="3"
          cursor="pointer"
          color="inherit"
          _dark={{
            color: "gray.400",
          }}
          _hover={{
            bg: "gray.100",
            _dark: {
              bg: "gray.900",
            },
            color: "gray.900",
          }}
          role="group"
          fontWeight="semibold"
          transition=".15s ease"
          {...rest}
        >
          {icon && (
            <Icon
              mx="2"
              boxSize="4"
              _groupHover={{
                color: color,
              }}
              as={icon}
            />
          )}
          {children}
        </Flex>
      );
    };
  
    const SidebarContent = (props) => (
      <Box
        as="nav"
        pos="fixed"
        top="0"
        left="0"
        zIndex="sticky"
        h="full"
        pb="10"
        overflowX="hidden"
        overflowY="auto"
        bg="white"
        _dark={{
          bg: "gray.800",
        }}
        border
        color="inherit"
        borderRightWidth="1px"
        w="60"
        {...props}
      >
        <Flex px="4" py="5" align="center">
          <Logo />
          <Text
            fontSize="2xl"
            ml="2"
            color="brand.500"
            _dark={{
              color: "white",
            }}
            fontWeight="semibold"
          >
            Choc UI
          </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex
          direction="column"
          as="nav"
          fontSize="sm"
          color="gray.600"
          aria-label="Main Navigation"
        >
          <NavItem icon={MdHome}>Home</NavItem>
          <NavItem icon={FaRss}>Articles</NavItem>
          <NavItem icon={HiCollection}>Collections</NavItem>
          <NavItem icon={FaClipboardCheck}>Checklists</NavItem>
          <NavItem icon={HiCode} onClick={integrations.onToggle}>
            Integrations
            <Icon
              as={MdKeyboardArrowRight}
              ml="auto"
              transform={integrations.isOpen && "rotate(90deg)"}
            />
          </NavItem>
          <Collapse in={integrations.isOpen}>
            <NavItem pl="12" py="2">
              Shopify
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem pl="12" py="2">
              Slack
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem pl="12" py="2">
              Zapier
            </NavItem>
          </Collapse>
          <NavItem icon={AiFillGift}>Changelog</NavItem>
          <NavItem icon={BsGearFill}>Settings</NavItem>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    );
  
    return (
      <Box
        as="section"
        bg="gray.50"
        _dark={{
          bg: "gray.700",
        }}
        minH="100vh"
      >
        <SidebarContent
          display={{
            base: "none",
            md: "unset",
          }}
        />
        <Drawer
          isOpen={sidebar.isOpen}
          onClose={sidebar.onClose}
          placement="left"
        >
          <DrawerOverlay />
          <DrawerContent>
            <SidebarContent w="full" borderRight="none" />
          </DrawerContent>
        </Drawer>
        <Box
          ml={{
            base: 0,
            md: 60,
          }}
          transition=".3s ease"
        >
          <Flex
            as="header"
            align="center"
            justify="space-between"
            w="full"
            px="4"
            bg="white"
            _dark={{
              bg: "gray.800",
            }}
            borderBottomWidth="1px"
            color="inherit"
            h="14"
          >
            <IconButton
              aria-label="Menu"
              display={{
                base: "inline-flex",
                md: "none",
              }}
              onClick={sidebar.onOpen}
              icon={<FiMenu />}
              size="sm"
            />
            <InputGroup
              w="96"
              display={{
                base: "none",
                md: "flex",
              }}
            >
              <InputLeftElement color="gray.500">
                <FiSearch />
              </InputLeftElement>
              <Input placeholder="Search for articles..." />
            </InputGroup>
  
            <Flex align="center">
              <Icon color="gray.500" as={FaBell} cursor="pointer" />
              <Avatar
                ml="4"
                size="sm"
                name="anubra266"
                src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/30869823?v=4"
                cursor="pointer"
              />
            </Flex>
          </Flex>
  
          <Box as="main" p="4">
            {/* Add content here, remove div below  */}
            <Box borderWidth="4px" borderStyle="dashed" rounded="md" h="96" />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    );
  };
```